# How to draw Toeplitz graph in Mathematica?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

My  trials are

```
GraphData["ToeplitzGraph"]
```

> GraphData::notdef: GraphData has no value associated with the specified argument(s).

and web search, in particular [that article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.09152.pdf) and [that article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/275866788_Some_Properties_of_Toeplitz_graphs), which does not bring a desired answer (Even some definitions are unclear to me.).

Comment: Your first link is broken.

Comment: *"Even some definitions are unclear to me."* It would be better to be clear about what you want to do precisely before asking how to implement it in Mathematica. "What is a Toeplitz graph?" would belong on Math.SE. I am not familiar with the concept, but some googling results in "A Toeplitz graph is a graph with a Toeplitz adjacency matrix.". You can use `ToeplitzMatrix` and `AdjacencyGraph`, e.g. `AdjacencyGraph@ToeplitzMatrix[{0, 1, 0, 1, 0}]`

Comment: @Szabolcs: Thank you. Fixed.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Thank you again. You are partly right, but in https://www.researchgate.net/publication/275866788_Some_Properties_of_Toeplitz_graphs another definition is used. How to write down an adjacency matrix, making use of that definition?

Comment: It seems to me that that is the same definition: all k-diagonals are constant (Toeplitz) and the matrix has only zeros and ones (it's an adjacency matrix).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not familiar with the concept of Toeplitz graphs, but the paper you linked says:

[image]

This is the same definition as [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-0348-0859-0_8), i.e.

> A Toeplitz graph is a graph with a [Toeplitz adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix).

Therefore, you can use [`ToeplitzMatrix`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToeplitzMatrix.html) with a vector of ones and zeros, starting with a zero (ensuring a zero diagonal).

The following code generates all labelled Toeplitz graphs on `n` vertices:

```
n = 6;
m = n - 1;
graphs = Table[
   AdjacencyGraph@ToeplitzMatrix[{0}~Join~IntegerDigits[k, 2, m]],
   {k, 0, 2^m - 1}
  ];
```

Let us look at the connected non-isomorphic ones from this list:

```
Select[ConnectedGraphQ]@DeleteDuplicatesBy[graphs, CanonicalGraph]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer.